# When does output buffer flush?

Tags: c++, c

Apart from manually calling flush, what is the condition that `cout` or `STDOUT(printf)` would flush?

Exiting the current scope or current function? Is it timed? Flush when the buffer is full (and how big is the buffer)?

Comment: For C and stdio, generally when it sees a newline ( "\n" ). I can't speak to cout or C++.

Comment: @CharlieBurns I don't think that's the case for `cout` though?

Comment: It's implementation defined.

Comment: It's platform dependent. See [The little endl that couldn't (pdf)](http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/C++ReportColumns/novdec95.pdf) and e.g. [setvbuf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/setvbuf.html)

Comment: If you're mixing cout and stdout, the answer is: undefined.

Comment: @kfsone They are different parts of the question...

Comment: @texasbruce, I changed my comment to refer to C and stdio only. Thanks.

Comment: @texasbruce I refreshed the page, and I don't see that edit.

Comment: Let me rephrase, if it is C and stdio going to a terminal, a \n will flush it. If it is headed for a file, I think it's when the buffer is full.

Comment: @CharlieBurns so it is a system dependent behavior? The underlying buffer is monitored by the system/terminal?

Comment: You have an answer now that appears to say "yes, it's system dependent". In C you can use setbuf(file, 0); and that makes it unbuffered if that's what you are looking for. Read the man page for setbuf et al.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `<stdio.h>` streams you can set the buffering mode using `setvbuf()`. It takes three buffering modes:

1. `_IOFBF`: the buffer is flushed when it is full or when a flush is explicitly requested.
2. `_IOLBF`: the buffer is flushed when a newline is found, the buffer is full, or a flush is requested.
3. `_IONBF`: the stream is unbuffered, i.e., output is sent as soon as available.

I had the impressino that the default setup for `stdout` is `_IOLBF`, for `stderr` it is `_IONBF`, and for other streams it is `_IOFBF`. However, looking at the C standard I don't find any indication on what the default is for any C stream.

For the standard C++ stream objects there is no equivalent to `_IOLBF`: if you want line buffer you'd use `std::endl` or, preferrably, `'\n'` and `std::flush`. There are a few setups for `std::ostream`, though:

1. You generally can use `buf.pubsetbuf(0, 0)` to turn a stream to be unbuffered. Since stream buffers can be implemented by users, it isn't guaranteed that the corresponding call to set the buffer is honored, though.
2. You can set `std::ios_base::unitbuf` which causes the stream to be flushed after each [properly implemented] output operations. By default `std::ios_base::unitbuf` is only set for `std::cerr`.
3. The normal setup for an `std::ostream` to flush the buffer when the buffer is full or when explicitly requested where, unfortunately, `std::endl` makes an explicit request to flush the buffer (causing performance problems in many cases because it tends to be used as a surrogate for `'\n'` which it is not).
4. An interesting one is the ability to `in.tie()` an output buffer to an input stream: if `in.tie()` contains a pointer to an `std::ostream` this output stream will be flushed prior to an attempt to read from `in` (assuming correctly implemented input operators, of course). By default, `std::cout` is `tie()`d to `std::cin`.
5. Nearly forgot an important one: if `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio()` wasn't called with `false` the standard C++ streams (`std::cin`, `std::cout`, `std::cerr` and `std::clog` and their `wchar_t` counterparts) are *probably* entirely unbuffered! With the default settings of `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(true)` the standard C and C++ streams can be used in a mixed way. However, since the C library is generally oblivious of the C++ library this means that the C++ standard stream objects can't do any buffering. Using `std::sync_with_stdio(true)` is *the* major performance problem with standard C++ stream objects!

Neither in C nor in C++ you can really control the size of buffers: the requests to set a non-zero buffer are allowed to be ignored and normally will be ignored. That is, the stream will pretty much be flushed at somewhat random places.

Comment: Can you point me to the reference of `out.setbuf`? I couldn't find it in the cpp documentation...

Comment: @texasbruce: It is a function on `std::streambuf`. You get the stream's stream buffer using `out.rdbuf()`.

Comment: Maybe change `out.setbuf` to `buf.setbuf`? I thought `out` refers to output stream... also since `unitbuf` is a constant for a stream, I cannot change it for `cout` right?

Comment: From this page http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin apparently `cin.tie` to `cout`... so every time `cin` gets data, it would flush the cout buffer.. interesting

Comment: @texasbruce: actually, `std::streambuf::setbuf()` is the `virtual` function (it should specify the contract, though). The public one to call on stream buffers is `std::streambuf::pubsetbuf()`. Note, that the only portable argument to call it with on the predefined stream, in particular the `std::filebuf`, are `0, 0` making the file stream unbuffered.

Comment: @texasbruce: OK, changed `out.setbuf()` to `buf.pubsetbuf()` which is more correct. Yes, `tie()` is interesting: the intend is to guarantee that output to `std::cout` appears before an attempt to read from `std::cin` is made, e.g., `std::cout << "enter name: "; std::cin >> name;` Hardly anybody is aware of this neat feature (and I also keep forgetting about it).

Comment: I have this code: `cin.tie(NULL); cout << "TEST"; cin >> x;`, and I was expecting the cin to be untied from cout, and it should read input first, and then output "TEST", but it still prints first.. why?

Comment: @texasbruce: Did you call `std::sync_with_stdio(false)`? If you didn't, the output will immediately be written to `stdout` and the buffering will be controlled there. Likewise, `std::cin` will effectively read from `stdin` which may decide to flush `stdout` (I don't think it is mandated but it is, at least, possible). Finally, I don't know if implementation generally do change the setup when `std::sync_with_stdio(true)` is called. I know that my implementation certainly changes its internal setup when there is no need to synchronize!

Comment: tie() is not just for the input streams; `cerr` is tied to `cout`